# Multiple config files in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to have multiple config files: one that has common info and one that has profile-specific info.  To do this, I have

**src/main/resources/application.yml**

```
myApp:
  foo: 3
```

**src/main/resources/application-myprofile.yml**

```
myApp:
  bar: xyzzy
```

When I run with `myprofile` as an active name, I get errors trying to initialize my beans:

**MyBean.java**

```
@Component class MyBean {
  @Value("${myApp.foo}") int foo;
}
```

with a

> Could not resolve placeholder 'myApp.foo' in value "{$myApp.foo}"

[This page](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/properties-with-spring-boot/) says that if there is a conflict, the profile configuration will win.  That apparently means that, since both files define `myApp`, the entire object from the profile is used.  Is there a way to get the fields only specified in the `application.yml` to be used while overriding some but not all in the profile config file?

I know that `application.yml` is being read, because if I replace the space prefixes with tabs, I get an error that tabs are not allowed.